# Pattern matching explanation in UNIX

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script as given below:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    mv "$file" "${file%_*}.txt"
done
```

This script renamed the file `CC_something_xyzgh_hh_ABCDEF.txt` to `CC_something_xyzgh_hh.txt`. But I am not clear on what exactly does.

I did a search in internet, but I could not find anything that answers my question.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: You can see [Shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${string%substring}

    Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.
```

**Example:**

```
sat:~# file="CC_something_xyzgh_hh_ABCDEF.txt"
sat:~# echo ${file%_*}
CC_something_xyzgh_hh
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are basically doing here is [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

The `${file%_*}` deletes the shortest matching pattern of the expanded value **from the end**. For example:

```
$ for file in *.txt; do echo "$file =====> ${file%_*}.txt"; done
CC_something_xyzgh_hh_ABCDEF.txt =====> CC_something_xyzgh_hh.txt
```

Similarly, to delete the longest match **from the end**, you use `%%`:

```
$ for file in *.txt; do echo "$file =====> ${file%%_*}.txt"; done 
CC_something_xyzgh_hh_ABCDEF.txt =====> CC.txt
```

To do something similar from the **beginning of the parttern**, you use `#` (shortest) and `##` (longest)

```
$ for file in *.txt; do echo "$file =====> ${file#*_}.txt"; done
CC_something_xyzgh_hh_ABCDEF.txt =====> something_xyzgh_hh_ABCDEF.txt.txt
```

```
$ for file in *.txt; do echo "$file =====> ${file##*_}.txt"; done
CC_something_xyzgh_hh_ABCDEF.txt =====> ABCDEF.txt.txt
```